# How does AI Platform (ML Engine) allocate resources to jobs?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm trying out a few experiments using Google's AI Platform and have a few questions regarding that.

Basically, my project is structured as per the docs with a trainer task and a separate batch prediction task. I want to understand how AI Platform allocates resources to the tasks I execute. Comparing it with the current SOTA solutions like Spark, Tensorflow and Pytorch is where my doubts arise.

These engines/ libraries have distributed workers with dedicated coordination systems and have separate distributed implementation of all the machine learning algorithms. Since my tasks are written using ScikitLearn, how do these computations parallellize across the cluster that is provisioned by AI Platform since sklearn doesn't have any such distributed computing capabilities?

Following the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/getting-started-training). The command I'm using,

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
  --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
  --package-path $TRAINING_PACKAGE_PATH \
  --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
  --region $REGION \
  --runtime-version=$RUNTIME_VERSION \
  --python-version=$PYTHON_VERSION \
  --scale-tier $SCALE_TIER
```

Any help/ clarifications would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing distributed training with sklearn? AFAIK, sklearn doesn't support distributed training. If you want to run multiple sklearn jobs within one ML Engine's training job, you can run different job on each worker. You can parse the env variable TF_CONFIG to learn the worker index to act accordingly.

Comment: yes thats what my doubt was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, AI Platform Training can't automatically distribute your scikit-learn tasks. It basically just sets up the cluster, deploys your package to each node, and runs it.

You might want to try a distributed backend such as Dask for scaling out the task -- it has a drop-in replacement for Joblib that can run scikit-learn pipelines on a cluster.

I found one tutorial here: https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/02/07/dask-sklearn-simple

Hope that helps!